# How to plot TradingView indicator based on monthly series onto a daily series chart

Tags: pine-script

I would like to plot weekly chart indicators/values on a daily or hourly chart. For example, showing the weekly 12 period exponential moving average plotted on a daily chart.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("", overlay=true)
w = ema(close, 12)
// Repainting version.
weeklyEma1 = security(syminfo.ticker, "W", w)
// No repaint version.
weeklyEma2 = security(syminfo.ticker, "W", w[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(weeklyEma1)
plot(weeklyEma2, color = color.orange)
```

Comment: And to reply to M Ramazoodle, the `12` length in `w`'s formula is a number of bars in the current timeframe, which is weeks when it is used in my code's `security()` calls, so it **will** yield _the weekly 12 period exponential moving average_ the OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

I think LucF's answer gets you there but I think if you are on a Daily chart, then "w" evaluates to basically, 12 days. So, I think what you could do is multiply the period in the moving average formula such that it accounts for the change in timeframe. So, for example, I would consider that on a Daily chart, to plot a Weekly moving average, would require an evaluation over 5 Trading Days. As it would follow, that 12 weeks would be 60 Trading Days, or "w" is the ema evaluated over 60 periods.
On the Hourly chart, this would need to be adjusted and becomes a little more tricky seeing as how there are only 6.5 hours per standard Trading Day. Fortunately the math works out and it's equivalent to 390 hours. As it would follow, that 12 weeks would be 390 standard Trading Hours, or "w" is the ema evaluated over 390 periods.
But, I'm going to create a new project and try the code.

```
//@version=4
study("MyTestSMAIndicator", overlay=true)
w = sma(close, 12)
w60 = sma(close, 60)
// Repainting version.
weeklySma1 = security(syminfo.ticker, "W", w)
// No repaint version.
weeklySma2 = security(syminfo.ticker, "W", w[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(w60)
plot(weeklySma1)
plot(weeklySma2, color = color.orange)
```

Comment: So, if you will notice, using the Security function, you will get a choppy line throughout the Daily chart. However, just plotting the value of "w" gives you a smooth line like you are used to seeing. I am unable to explain this at my experience level?